# dynamic attachment of event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just trying a small experiment in js. It's something like this; I have a `ul` and below that about 5 `li`, now I attach an event handler for click on the 1st `li` , using a selector like below:

```
     var elem = $('ul li:nth-child('+ i +')');
```

Now I add the function funk, like so:

```
var funk = function() {
    return i < 5 ? i++ : i = 0 ;
}
```

Now what I want to happen is once the first `li` is clicked, I want the event handler to be attached to the next `li`, and when I click on the `li`, the click event should be attached to the `li` after that and so on ...

Now I have written the following code so far:

```
            var i = 0;

            $('document').ready(function(){
                str = funk();
                console.log(str);

                    var elem = $('ul li:nth-child('+ i +')');

                    elem.on('click' , function(){
                        console.log('logged');
                        funk();
                    });
            });

            var funk = function() {
                  return i < 5 ? i++ : i = 0 ;
            }
```

Now there are some obvious errors in the code that I am not able to iron out, for some reason the `funk()` function itself does't function as the I is never incremented.

Can somebody help me attach a dynamic event handler?

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/0nw4d43f/1/)**

Ae-x.

Comment: [Up Dated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nw4d43f/2/)

Comment: @ozil i taught js had variable hoisting that put all the variables before any other code during run time .

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, the problem is with declaration. Move func definition before it gets called.

The problem is with func function. It is a variable, so it gets declared initially and set to undefined, then all lines will gets executed but func is undefined so it will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a recursive solution for same. This adds handlers for next list items only on click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  addEventHandlerForNextItem(i);

  function addEventHandlerForNextItem(num) {
    var elem = $('ul li:nth-child(' + num + ')');
    elem.on('click', function() {
      console.log('element:' + elem[0].textContent);
      alert('element:' + elem[0].textContent);
      i = i + 1;
      addEventHandlerForNextItem(i);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

not the prittest, but heres how i managed to attached the event handler dynamically ::

```
            var i = 1;

            var funk = function() {
                  return i < 5 ? ++i : i = 1 ;
            }

            changeHanderler = function(){
                str = funk();
                console.log(str);
                var elem = $('ul li:nth-child('+ i +')');
                elem.on('click.ga' , function(){
                    console.log('logged');
                    elem.off('click.ga');
                    changeHanderler();
                });

            }

            $('document').ready(function(){
                elem = $('ul li:nth-child('+ i +')');

                elem.on('click.ga' , function(){
                    changeHanderler();
                    console.log('logged');
                    elem.off('click.ga');
                });

            });
```

not pritty but effective , also excessive usage of `on()` and `off()` jquery functions , maybe should have gone for the `one()` function.